# How to install certificate on Windows

Tags: python, windows, ssl-certificate

Trying to validate my certificate and getting the following error: failed to open CA file: No such process

when I run in Python

```
print(ssl.get_default_verify_paths())
```

Result: cafile: None, capath: None

SSL_CERT_FILE AND SSL_CERT_DIR are shown, but how do i create a ca certificate containing this information in Windows?